# Publish app with google maps V2 on google play

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Previously I have implemented Google maps v1  .It had publishing key and debug separately .But now i have implemented Google maps v2 with the help of [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) tutorial.In it they haven't mentioned any publishing key .Do we need  publishing key to publish app on google play

Comment: Yes you need a key for publishing. It is described in the tutorial in chapter 4.1

Comment: will u plz provide me url of that tutorial .i have searced and have not got

Comment: will we use MD5 to make publish key...

Comment: MD5 will not work with v2. You need SHA-1. Will add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a release key for publishing you app to the Google Play Store.

A tutorial can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Note that you need the SHA-1 fingerprint of your certificate as stated in the given link:

> **Release certificate:** The Android SDK tools generate this certificate
>   when you do a "release" build with either ant program or Eclipse. You
>   can also generate this certificate using the keytool program. This
>   certificate can be used with an app you release to the world. Once you
>   have the correct certificate for your needs, you can display its SHA-1
>   fingerprint using the keytool program.

Comment: That tutorial only tells us how to put a map in an app its does not cover publishing, just the  creation of a 'hello maps' application.